# Fedora 16 GUI doesn't start

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, xfce, fedora-16

I installed Fedora 16 about a week ago on my computer, using the live CD with the default partition settings. However, since yesterday my computer won't boot. First I got an error message that I had to run `fsck`/`e2fsck` in recovery mode, that went well, but after that the Fedora GUI wouldn't start. I either get the message Fedora couldn't start or only the wallpaper of the login screen appears, but with no GUI elements.

I could get to another console using `Ctrl+alt+Fx` and tried to reinstall my desktop (I have xfce running, I tried reinstalling both gnome and xfce), but whenever I tried to do something with yum I got the message that I have 0 bytes left on my hard disk. However, when booting with a live-cd it appears that I have 160GB free, and after removing some large files I still got the same message.

Of course I want to be able to boot properly again, but I have absolutely no idea where to start, where to find the right error logs etc. So what can I do to get Fedora working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently linux has dumped it's core in such a way that it took up over 40 GB of disk space on the root partition. As a result, the root partition was full and Fedora couldn't boot.